# How to align at keyword arguments in Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Using the [aligner](https://atom.io/packages/aligner), I get the following formatting of a Python function definition:

```
def get_auth_token(username = config.get('username', 'foo'), 
password                    = config.get('password', 'bar'), 
base_url                    = config.get('api_url', 'bla')):
```

However, I would like it to look like this:

```
def get_auth_token(username = config.get('username', 'foo'), 
                   password = config.get('password', 'bar'), 
                   base_url = config.get('api_url', 'bla')):
```

I would like all the (keyword) arguments to be left-aligned to the first one. (The argument variables happen to be all the same length here, but I would also like alignment of the `=` signs if they are not of equal length). Is there a package/shortcut key to achieve this in Atom?